# Use of BaseX in a Openshift Web application

Tags: openshift, basex

How can I use BaseX in an Openshift Java Web application?

I have set up an application in Openshift. This application has a Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge. I deploy Web applications to it by sending the WAR with an SFTP client. I would like to start a BaseX server so that the servlets in this application can use it as clients.

I have tried to start the server by calling the following instructions:

```
        String folder = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR");
        if (folder == null) folder = System.getProperty("user.home");
        System.setProperty("org.basex.path", folder);
        server = new BaseXServer("-p15000");
```

As additional informaiton, the basex.jar file (BaseX's JAR file) is at the WEB-INF/lib directory. Also, I put there an empty file named ".basex", to prevent BaseX from creating the ".basex" configuration file in its default location. In Openshift, the environment variable "OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR" is a data directory, and I set the "org.basex.path" property to this data directory, so that BaseX stores the database files there. Besides, I start BaseX at port 15000, which, in Openshift, is available for binding (see https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port).

The code above works in my development environment, but doesn't work in Openshift. The error is the following:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
    org.basex.BaseXServer.<init>(BaseXServer.java:106)
    org.basex.BaseXServer.<init>(BaseXServer.java:65)
    x.NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:44)
    x.NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:116)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

### Update

Using dirkk's suggestion, I was able to start the server. But Openshift also has a different internal IP, so I also had to inform the local IP to which the server should bind. The local IP allowed by Openshift is in the environment variable **OPENSHIFT_{cartridge_name}_IP**. Since my cartridge is Tomcat (JBoss EWS), this environment variable is OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP. So, the command for starting became:

```
server = new BaseXServer("-p15000", "-e15001", "-n" + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP"));
```

But there is still an error that I don't know how to fix: when I call server.stop(), an exception with text "Connection refused" is thrown and the server remains running.

```
Mar 05, 2014 8:19:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [NewServlet] in context with path [/basextest] threw exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.basex.BaseXServer.stop(BaseXServer.java:333)
    at org.basex.BaseXServer.<init>(BaseXServer.java:93)
    at org.basex.BaseXServer.<init>(BaseXServer.java:65)
    at x.NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:112)
    at x.NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:128)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In short, **I can start the server, but I can't stop it**.

### Update 2

Using Andy Bunce's suggestion, I have created a "Do It Yourself 0.1" gear on OpenShift and managed to install BaseX on it. The BaseX server is now running in this gear. Now, I'm not sure how to connect to the BaseX server from a BaseXClient hosted in another gear (a Tomcat 7 application). Could someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository https://github.com/Quodatum/openshift-basex-quick-start has an alternative way to run BaseX on OpenShift. It uses `basexhttp` rather than the WAR.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I will test it when I have time.

Comment: Thank you again. I've created a "Do It Yourself 0.1" application on OpenShift and managed to install BaseX on it using this quick start. The BaseX server is now running in this application. Now, I'm not sure how to connect to the BaseX server from a BaseXClient hosted in another application (a Tomcat 7 application). Could you provide some guidance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not tried it server to server but, port forwarding might be an option see http://quodatum.wordpress.com/2014/06/15/how-to-connect-a-local-basexclient-to-a-server-running-on-openshift/ and this https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/accessing-an-server-port-running-in-openshift-from-another-openshift-image

Comment: I have been using the BaseX HTTP server with RESTXQ (as already available from the BaseX installation) based on your quickstart and it works very well. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

BaseX also binds to another socket, used for event handling. You can set this port to some port allowed by OpenShift using the `-e` argument, i.e.

```
server = new BaseXServer("-p15000", "-e15001");
```

Comment: +1 This worked for connection. But Openshift also has a different internal IP, so I also had to inform the local IP to which the server should bind. The local IP allowed by Openshift is in the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_{cartridge_name}_IP`. Since my cartridge is Tomcat (JBoss EWS), the command for starting became `server = new BaseXServer("-p15000", "-e15001", "-n" + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP"));` . But there is still an error that I don't know how to fix: when I call **server.stop()**, an exception with text "Connection refused" is thrown and the server remains running.

Comment: @anonymous The `stop()` issue seems like a bug to me. You might want to report that one on the mailing list of BaseX. For now, you can also `kill` the server process, but of course a graceful shutdown would be better.